# In flask's documentation for celery, why do celery tasks need names?

Tags: python, flask, celery, celery-task

In the documentation, the @celery.task decorator is not passed arguments, yet in the GitHub example, it is named "tasks.add". Why is it? When I remove the name, the example no longer works, complaining of

> `KeyError: '__main__.add'`

[1] http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/
[2] https://github.com/thrisp/flask-celery-example/blob/master/app.py#L25

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Flask documentation the task `name` was not set because the code is assumed to be inside a `tasks` module, so the task's name will be automatically generated as `tasks.add`, in the Celery docs:

> Every task must have a unique name, and a new name will be generated
>   out of the function name if a custom name is not provided

Check the [Names](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-names) section of the Celery docs for more info.

In the other example on Github, the author sets the name explicitly instead of relying on the automatic naming, which will be `__main__.tasks` if running as the main module, which is the case when running the Flask server.

**Update** on why you're having this issue:

The task is being sent from the function `hello_world` when you access the `/test` page by passing `x` and `y`:

```
res = add.apply_async((x, y))
```

Because the task `add` is inside the `__main__` module it will be named `__main__.add` and sent to the worker with this name, but on the other hand the worker that you started using:

```
celery worker -A app.celery
```

Has this task registered as `app.add` that's why you're getting this error:

```
[2014-10-10 10:32:29,540: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type '__main__.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-names for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'timelimit': (None, None), 'utc': True, 'chord': None, 'args': (2787476, 36096995), 'retries': 0, 'expires': None, 'task': '__main__.add', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': None, 'id': '804e10a0-2569-4338-a5e3-f9e07689d1d1'} (218b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/env/celery/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 455, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: '__main__.add'
```

Check the output of the worker:

```
[tasks]
  . app.add
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
```

Celery only sends the task name to the worker to execute it, so when you explicitly set the task name the `hello_world` function will send the task with this name which is registered in the worker.

**Update**:

The task name can be whatever you want, it can just be `add`, and your celery tasks don't have to be in a `tasks` module at all, to understand more about task names try this:

Remove the explicit task name and start a worker:

```
celery worker -A app.celery
```

in another terminal window, `cd` to the code directory and start an interactive python shell and try this:

```
>>> import app
>>> app
<module 'app' from 'app.pyc'>
>>> app.add
<@task: app.add of app:0xb6a29a6c>
>>> # check the name of the task
... app.add.name
'app.add'
>>> t = app.add.delay(2, 3)
>>> t.result
5
```

As you can see we didn't use an explicit name and it worked as expected because the name of task from where we sent it is the same as registered in the worker (see above).

Now back to why you got this error when you removed the task name, the task is sent from `app.py` right, in the same directory run this:

```
$ python -i app.py
```

Then interrupt the Flask server with `Ctrl` + `C`, and try this:

```
>>> add.name
'__main__.add'
```

As you can see this is why you got this error and not because you removed the task name.

Comment: I head seen that in the docs. My primary question is why having allowing automatic naming as __main__.tasks flat out breaks. I read somewhere about needing to adjust celeryconfig.py, but I'm unclear as to what the default are.

Comment: @ehfeng it doesn't have anything to do with the config, I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: @ehfeng I updated my answer with more details so you understand what was causing the error.

Comment: Yup thanks so much! I think I finally get it now. This was really helpful.